# Border-top shadow and triangle down in css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve something like this in CSS. Is it possible? How?
I can create a border top with shadow as well as a triangle down, but the issue if I do this is that there's a border on 3 sides of the triangle so the rendering is not the same.

Many thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<span class="bubble">Speech bubble with a border</span>
```

css:

```
body { padding: 100px 10px;text-align: center;}
.bubble {
    background-color: #eee;border: 2px solid #333;box-shadow: 5px 1px 5px #888888;border-radius: 5px;color: #333;display: inline-block;font:16px/24px sans-serif;padding: 12px 24px;position: relative;}
.bubble:after,
.bubble:before {
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;border-right: 20px solid transparent;border-top: 20px solid #eee;bottom: -20px;content: '';left: 50%;margin-left: -20px;position: absolute;}
.bubble:before {
    border-left: 23px solid transparent;border-right: 23px solid transparent;border-top: 23px solid;border-top-color: inherit;bottom: -23px;margin-left: -23px;}
```